# How to create database context/connection with JayData

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jaydata

I am using JaydData with Backbone JS. On the start page of application I am using the JayData context as:

```
$data.Entity.extend('$todo.Types.ToDoEntry', {
    Id: { type: 'int', key: true, computed: true },
    Value: { type: 'string' },
    CreatedAt: { type: 'datetime' },
    ModifiedAt: { type: 'datetime' },
    Done: { type: 'bool' }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend('$todo.Types.ToDoContext', {
    TodoEntries: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $todo.Types.ToDoEntry }
});

$todo.context = new $todo.Types.ToDoContext({ name: provider, databaseName: 'todo' });
$todo.context.onReady({
    success: updateView,
    error: function () {
    $todo.context = null;
    updateView();
}
```

On this page `$todo.context` is available for executing database operations. 
But when I navigate to some other page of application, `$todo.context` is not available.
How can I get the `$todo.context` on all pages of the Backbone application?

Thanks.

Comment: are you actually navigating away from your start page to your new page? or is it handled internally as a single page app

Comment: @Quince I am using Backbone routes for naviation. So basically it ia a single page app. But problem is when I open the app second time, how do I get the context at that moment.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to reuse the code you provided on other pages. If you wanted to save it accross multiple pages you could look into attaching it to a [session variable](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Good luck in your endeavors!

Comment: Better provide an elaborated answer with code sample.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write a new JS file with the '$.todo.context' and load it as a module using require js, 
This way you can define in every page, this dependency.

Take a look in how to use RequireJS.

http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

I have a post with this topic in my blog, unfortunately it's only available in portuguese. try to use google to translate.

http://www.rcarvalhojs.com/backbone/2014/06/03/comecando-require-backbone.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is weird, try to attach it in the global window context.